# How to add two elements with independend "rendered"-attributes in Primefaces lightBox?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have my Primefaces lightBox set up like this:

```
<p:lightBox>
<h:outputLink value='#'>
KLICK
<h:outputLink>

<f:facet name="inline">

TWO ELEMENTS SHOULD GO HERE

</f:facet>
</p:lightBox>
```

I tried  but even if both panel have the attribute "rendered='true'" only the latter one shows up.

Comment: something similar happened with `<f:facet name="header"/>` while I was using `p:dialog`. Are you explicitly setting the `rendered="true"` for both methods or you are getting that value from a backing bean method?

Comment: I am getting the value from a bean method, but I also had the problem, when I explicitly set 'rendered="true"' for test purpose. BalusC's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facets can have only one child component. Wrap them in a `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<f:facet name="inline">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:someComponent rendered="..." />
        <h:otherComponent rendered="..." />
    </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
```